# Randomise all password in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a MySQL database with a table that contains usernames and passwords. I want a bash script or MySQL statement that will randomise all the passwords.

I can reset one password with something like

```
select md5(rand()) as password;
```

I can loop through with a bash read while loop. Just need help putting it all together.

Yews I know there should not be passwords stored in the clear, it's a legacy system we are moving people away from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `users` SET `password` = md5(rand())
```

Comment: Fantastic. I thought that would have set them all to same password but it worked. I used  UPDATE `accounts` SET `password` = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 8);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to just `CONCAT` the current password into the md5, to keep them all unique.

```
UPDATE passwords SET password = md5(CONCAT(RAND(), password))
```

Comment: you're right but my reason for reset was a they were compromised and doing this would have been able to derive new passwords from the old ones.

Comment: That's why you CONCAT the RAND into it, so it's got an element of randomness making it impossible to derive the new passwords.